# Selecting Bootstrap's drop-down menu items programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have a Bootstrap 3 drop-down menu (the standard component) and we would like to change the selected item programmatically. We tried to modify the data-selected attributes, but changes are not reflected in the UI.

Is there are standard way to modify programmatically the item selected in a Bootstrap drop-down menu?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://bootply.com/VkfhGMSCu3

Comment: That seem to be the opposite. I need to modify the value and have the UI to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery something like

```
 $('#item').on('selected', function(){
//do your changes...
}
```

EDIT:

Something has to trigger the selection, for example when the page is loaded:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#item').select();
});
```

Comment: That seem to be the opposite. I need to modify the value and have the UI to reflect the changes.

Comment: @seba Could you be a little bit more specific on what exactly you try to achive. Maby give an example.

Comment: Er... it is very difficult to be more specific than that. I have a Bootstrap drop-down menu. I want a piece of Javascript that will select an item in the menu, as if the user did it. But I want to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a way to do this, too - Am I totally blind or does the documentation completly skip this? What I ended up doing is using the `.click()` method of the corresponding link elements.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" id="dd-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">...</a>
  <ul id="dd-ul" class="dropdown-menu user-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="dd-opt1" role="menu" value="opt1">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="dd-opt2" role="menu" value="opt2">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="dd-opt3" role="menu" value="opt3">...</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, if the desired `value` of the dropdown item to be selected is stored in some variable `ddselected`, one can select that dropdown item via:

```
$("#dd-" + ddselected).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a value to a function and you simply want to make a selection based on the text values in the dropdown, try this:

```
 function yourAutoSelectFunc(YourTextValue) {
     $('#YourDropDownUL').find('li:contains("' + YourTextValue + '")').click();
 }
```